# In an R data frame, for a given row, how can I find what percentage a value in column A is of a value in column B?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

Say I have a data frame as follows:

```
dataDF <- data.frame(
   cola = c(10, 15, 30),
   colb = c(100, 300, 800)
   )


   cola   colb
1  10     100
2  15     300
3  30     800
```

How can I find what percent column a row 1 (10) is of column b row 1 (100), and so on for rows 2 and 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way which is useful if you want to have a column containing the percentages is this:

```
library(dplyr)

dataDF <- data.frame(
  cola = c(10, 15, 30),
  colb = c(100, 300, 800)
)
dataDF2 <- mutate(dataDF, colc = cola/colb*100)
dataDF2
  cola colb  colc
1   10  100 10.00
2   15  300  5.00
3   30  800  3.75
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `prop.table` and specify the `margin`.  Here it is by row, so we use `1` and if it is column, it would be 2

```
prop.table(as.matrix(dataDF), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `data.table package`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataDF)[, colc := cola/colb*100]

> dataDT
   cola colb  colc
1:   10  100 10.00
2:   15  300  5.00
3:   30  800  3.75
```